# Windows 10 Mobile system folders

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Can we access system folders like C: from code on Windows 10 Mobile ? I know it is possible to view the files in the developers version of the OS if you create a shortcut of drive C:\ on your computer and then drag and drop it to your phone, does the framework actually provide access to it or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [file pickers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.aspx) you have all the permissons on C:\ or D:\ drives but I don't think you can access system files.

Comment: Well that's a pity, but that is not what I need. I need to have access to the folders where apps store there files.